# Java Method describes all fields of any Object need to be improved

Tags: java

Colleagues,  this is my method which describes all attributes (fields) of the any Object:

```
public static void describeObjectFields(Object o) {

    System.out.println("Object description: " + o.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ": ");

    for (Field field: o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

        field.setAccessible(true);
        String name = field.getName();

        Object value;
        try {
            value = field.get(o);
            /*
                if (value.toString().contains("com.comp."))
                {
                    LOG.info("There is an Object in the described class " + value.getClass().getCanonicalName() );
                    System.out.println(value.getClass().getFields().toString() );
                    for (Field field1 :  value.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                        field1.setAccessible(true);
                        String name1 = field1.getName();
                        Object value1 = null;
                        value1 = field1.get(value1);
                        System.out.println(name1 + " -> " + value1);
                    }

                } else {
                */
            System.out.println(name + " -> " + value);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine with primitive types (string, data, int...)
Could anybody improve this method to print not primitive types but complex (when one of object fields is a object too).

**UPDATE**

According to @Jon Skeet advise lets the program will be looks like

```
package App;

public class Kitchen {


    double sqr;
    int windows;


    public Kitchen(float sqr, int windows) {
        this.sqr = sqr;
        this.windows = windows;
    }


    public double getSqr() {
        return sqr;
    }

    public void setSqr(double sqr) {
        this.sqr = sqr;
    }

    public int getWindows() {
        return windows;
    }

    public void setWindows(int windows) {
        this.windows = windows;
    }
}


package App;
public class Flat {

    Kitchen kitchen;

    double sqr;
    int windows;
    int rooms;


    public Flat(Kitchen kitchen, double sqr, int windows, int rooms) {
        this.kitchen = kitchen;
        this.sqr = sqr;
        this.windows = windows;
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public Kitchen getKitchen() {
        return kitchen;
    }

    public void setKitchen(Kitchen kitchen) {
        this.kitchen = kitchen;
    }

    public double getSqr() {
        return sqr;
    }

    public void setSqr(float sqr) {
        this.sqr = sqr;
    }

    public int getWindows() {
        return windows;
    }

    public void setWindows(int windows) {
        this.windows = windows;
    }

    public int getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(int rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }
}



package App;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class App {


    public static void  main (String [] args)
    {

        Kitchen kit = new Kitchen(12, 1 );

        Flat flat = new Flat(kit, 32.32, 5, 4);


        App.describeObjectFields(flat);

    }


    public static void describeObjectFields(Object o) {

        System.out.println("Object description: " + o.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ": ");

        for (Field field: o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

            field.setAccessible(true);
            String name = field.getName();

            Object value;
            try {
                value = field.get(o);
            /*
                if (value.toString().contains("com.comp."))
                {
                    LOG.info("There is an Object in the described class " + value.getClass().getCanonicalName() );
                    System.out.println(value.getClass().getFields().toString() );
                    for (Field field1 :  value.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                        field1.setAccessible(true);
                        String name1 = field1.getName();
                        Object value1 = null;
                        value1 = field1.get(value1);
                        System.out.println(name1 + " -> " + value1);
                    }

                } else {
                */
                System.out.println(name + " -> " + value);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result i receive

```
Object description: App.Flat: 
kitchen -> App.Kitchen@140e19d
sqr -> 32.32
windows -> 5
rooms -> 4
```

but would like

```
Object description: App.Flat:    
     Object description: App.Kitchen: 
      sqr -> 12
      windows -> 1 
sqr -> 32.32 
windows -> 5 
rooms -> 4
```

How?

Comment: It will already do that, just calling toString() on the value implicitly. It would really help if you could provide a short but complete program with actual output and expected output...

Comment: You *maybe* should take a look at `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils#describe()`

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `toString` method for each type you want to print.

For example, if you want to print an instance of YourObject in a readable way, you should write something like this:

```
public class YourObject
{
    private int yourField1;
    private int yourField2;

    public YourObject(int f1, int f2)
    {
        yourField1 = f1;
        yourField2 = f2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
         return "YourObject[yourField1=" + yourField1 + ", yourField2=" + yourField2 + "]");
    }

}
```

That given, you can do something like this:

```
AnotherObject obj = new AnotherObject();
obj.setYourObject(new YourObject(1,2));
```

And when you call:

```
describeObjectFields(obj);
```

You will get:

```
YourObject[yourField1=1, yourField2=2]
```

**UPDATE**

In your case, you should do something like this in your Kitchen class:

```
public class Kitchen {
    // your instance variables, constructor, getters and setters, etc.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("sqr: " + sqr + ", windows: " + windows);
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer, just remove the extra space you typed in `public String to String()`.

Comment: From the example above i can't understand how to get response like Object description: App.Flat:    
     Object description: App.Kitchen: 
      sqr -> 12
      windows -> 1 
sqr -> 32.32 
windows -> 5

Comment: In your Kitchen object, you must override the `toString` method. I updated my answer, take a look. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot. Is it possible to describe object with out adding "to string" method? I have some classes which are automatically genenerated by cxf wsdl2java utility and mannualy added method will be delete after regenerating.

Comment: @May12: without using external libraries, I'm quite sure the answer is "no". If you don't want to override all those "toString" methods (or you can't, as you said), then I strongly recommend RC's comment at your question, thus you should give a look at Apache Commons' BeanUtil, especially the static "describe" method, which can automate your "writing details" needs. :)